# Using dsize:<500 parameter in snort

Tags: snort

I am trying to make a rule to alert when downloading a `.jpg` file less than certain size. I used the parameter `dsize:<500`.
But it is not alerting when I tried to run a `.pcap` file containing a `jpg` less than 500MB.

Did I use the parameter correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is not correct. As [documented](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node33.html#SECTION00467000000000000000):

```
3.6.7 dsize
The dsize keyword is used to test the __packet payload__ size. This may be used to check for abnormally sized packets that might cause buffer overflows.
```

Thus, it is about the payload of a **packet**. It is not about the payload size of a HTTP body, since the body can be spread over multiple packets, it can be or start in the same packet as the HTTP header, it can be compressed ...

Comment: thankyou steffen, can you please suggest what can we add to make alert to detect certain payload size of http body.

Comment: @bura: This is a different question and should not be asked as a comment. But in short: I don't think there is a generic way to do this. One could try to match against the Content-length header but one cannot have an integer comparison for the size given there. Also there are other ways where the http body length isn't even known up-front.